# How to get latest date from three passed in date parameters in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need create a PLSQL function to return the latest date from three passed in date parameters.

For Example:

```
theLatestDate    date;

theLatestDate := GetLatestDate(Date1, Date2, Date3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create a new function. This is what `greatest` does:

```
theLatestDate := greatest(Date1, Date2, Date3);
```

Details in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions069.htm#SQLRF00645

The "opposite" of `greatest()` is `least()`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions087.htm#SQLRF00657

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks! greatest! greatest! greatest!

Comment: BTW, is there a function to return the oldest date? (opposite of latest)

Comment: use the LEAST() function for oldest date